# Differences between sqlite, SQL AND MYSQL and learning tips

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I have quite done with my web-programming skills and now i thought of learning database languages.

But I am confuse with the difference between `sqlite`, `SQL` and `MySQL`.

So can anyone recommend me the steps of learning database with above languages(zero knowledge).

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL" ?? SQL is a query language - not a product. MySQL and SQLite both use SQL as their query language (as do just about any of the relational databases)...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Start to learn one engine and I recommend (Microsoft) SQL Server, and the conversion will be easy.

But it is important to note that SQL Server and MySQL support stored procedures but SQLite does not.

SQLite is file-based, SQL Server and MySQL are server-based

Comment: I would recommend using some free software (so against using Microsoft SQL). sqlite is really easy to use (e.g. inside a C program).

Answer (score 13):

SQL is query language. MySQL is client-server relational database management system (RDBMS). Sqlite is embeddable relational database management system.

Comment: @Dorji - If you want to learn RDBMSes then yes, you'll need to learn SQL. The problem is that SQL is slightly different for each implementation (though I'm not 100% on that as I'm not a DBA). Therefore, you should start with MySql or SQLite and then one of them to start.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, Can you just write me the sequence of three for learning database for beginner like me without any description.

Comment: @Dorji - I'm not sure I follow? What do you mean by "sequence of three"?

Comment: @Andrey, you are suggesting me to learn MySql prior to Sql right?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, I mean the sequence of learning SQL, sqlite, MYSQL?

Comment: @Dorji - MySql *USES* SQL. SQL is just a *language* like C++ or Python. There are implementations of SQL such as *MySql*, *SQLite*, *Oracle* etc. To "learn" SQL, you need to pick an implementation (such as MySql), and Google for "MySql Tutorial". Hope this makes things more clear.

Answer (score 6):

**SQL** - Structured Query Language - (To query database)

**MySQL** - Client Server Database - (Uses SQL to manage data, Has User Interface (UI))

**SQLite** - Small version of MySQL - (for battery operated devices)

More :

**SQLite:**

- easier to setup
- great for temporary (testing databases)
- great for rapid development
- great for embedding in an application
- doesn't have user management
- doesn't have many performance features
- doesn't scale well.

**MySQL:**

- far more difficult/complex to set up
- better options for performance tuning
- can scale well if tuned properly
- can manage users, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I best recommend to use MySQL first for you to become more familiar on its basic functionality which I suppose  you must learn first.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is the relational database management system most popularly used in mobile device as a database for local storage. Its used in embedded system.

SQL is also known as Structured Query language is the based on relational algebra. sqlite, MySQL, MSSQL and etcs are part of SQL. They use all sql syntax but each database (sqlite, MySQL, MSSQL) have their own query convention

MySQl is a large scale entriprise database also known as Relational database management system. These database are very scalable and can handle huge terabyes of data.

Other database are PostgreSQL and there are many other...

Answer (score 0):

SQL stands for Structured Query Language; it is a language designed to access and manage data stored in a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS). 
You can add, retrieve, remove, or access data within a database with the help of SQL at any time using some basic queries.
In short, SQL not only allows users to access data stored in a Relational Database Management System but also creates, deletes databases and sets permissions on database tables, views and procedures.

SQLite is a software library that provides a Relational Database Management System.
The lite in SQLite means light weight in terms of setup, database administration, and required resource. 
SQLite has the following noticeable features: self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration and transactional.
SQLite is the lite form of SQL which runs on low powered devices or the devices with low memory such as mobile devices, Personal Digital Assistant (PDA) or pocket music players.
SQLite is not a client–server database engine. Rather, it is embedded into the end program.
SQLite is file-based whereas SQL is a server based.

MySQL is an open-source Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) that uses Structured Query Language (SQL).
It is used for a wide range of purposes, including data warehousing, e-commerce, and logging applications. 
The most common use for MySQL is for the purpose of a web database.